# Different PTR record resolve in DNS my DNS server and the public DNS server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, ptr-record

I have created a PTR Record for Mail matters on my DNS server which can be seen as public. But after a day it is not recognized by `mxtoolbox.com`. I have checked every possible syntax errors but there where none.

When I do a Dig on the record I get two different results.

When the DNS server is my DNS I get the correct return record. But with public DNS, it returns like the below line where 188 is the first octet of my IP.

> 188.in-addr.arpa.       1798    IN      SOA     pri.authdns.ripe.net. dns.ripe.net. 1541053975 3600 600 864000 3600

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

PTR record should be added to the DNS server on which reverse zone for your subnet is **delegated**. Otherwise, other servers on the Internet will not find PTR record you created.

Comment: My DNS server is accessable from outside and I have other PTR records working fine. It's about a week that I have this problem and could not find the problem.
I have defined the reverse zone correctly.

Comment: Thank you Slipper. I got it after the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

The PTR record as seen by someone from the internet, must be added to a DNS server serving the IP subnet in question.

If you try:   `dig -x  @mydns.server my.ip.add.ress`    and `dig -x  @8.8.8.8 my.ip.add.ress`, and the result differs, then Your DNS server is not delegated to handle the IP subnet for reverse lookups.

So the error is related to changes at Your ISP. If you have a /28 net , the owner of the /24 net (or whatever is appropriate in Your case)  must delegate Your /28 net to Your DNS, or provide the PTR records for you

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get it.
So the ISP who has given the IP should define the PTR record. 
I didn't know this. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: cool. "If it worked before", then some changes must have been don at the ISP end.